# How can I ensure that I reset login permissions to MULTI_USER upon SQL script failure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following SQL script:

```
USE MyDatabase

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Write to tables here

COMMIT TRANSACTION

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

I want to make sure that my database is not accessed while the script is running, which is why I am setting the database to `SINGLE_USER` at the top.

Now, if anything inside the transaction fails (e.g. syntax error) I will never reset the database back to `MULTI_USER` which means it will be stuck in single user mode permanently (not what I want).

Is there a way to ensure we always go back to `MULTI_USER`, even on failure?

I guess I'm looking for the equivalent of a `finally` block in SQL, but from what I have read this doesn't exist.  Is there another way?

It's worth noting that I cannot move the `ALTER DATABASE` commands into the transaction, as this is not permitted (since they are committed immediately).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a [TRY CATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to make sure you always go back to `MULTI_USER`.

You will just need to move the command to switch back to `MULTI_USER` right after the `TRY CATCH` block, since FINALLY is not supported in SQL Server.

I ran a quick test with the following SQL and it worked as expected in SQL Server 2005. Just make sure you `ROLLBACK` the transaction in the `CATCH` block. I used `SELECT 1/0` to force the code into the `CATCH` block. For debugging purposes, I added the `SELECT user_access_desc ...` statements to show that the database was indeed switching from single user back to multi user mode.

```
USE MyDatabase

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

SELECT user_access_desc from sys.databases WHERE Name = 'MyDatabase'

DECLARE @errNum AS INT
DECLARE @errMsg AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @errNum = 0

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SELECT 1/0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    SELECT @errNum = ERROR_NUMBER(), @errMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END CATCH

IF @errNum <> 0
    SELECT 'An error occurred: ' + CAST(@errNum AS VARCHAR) + '- ' + @errMsg

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET MULTI_USER
GO

SELECT user_access_desc from sys.databases WHERE Name = 'MyDatabase'
```

**EDIT**
In my original answer, I had the `ALTER ... MULTI_USER` statement inside both the `TRY` and the `CATCH` block, but that was unnecessary so I moved the statement to right after the `TRY CATCH` block. I also added some error reporting. Some things to watch out for with this approach are:

1. If you do any error handling or reporting, you'll need to make sure that SQL doesn't error. I would probably write the `@errNum` and `@errMsg` values to a table (wrapped in a TRY CATCH), switch back to `MULTI_USER` mode, and then perform whatever other error handling measures that are required, as the local variables will go out of scope after the `GO` statement.
2. Some errors are unaffected by `TRY CATCH`. The documentation I linked to above does list out what those conditions are.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  Will this handle syntax errors inside the `TRY` block?  I'll try this when I'm back at work on Monday.

Comment: Apologies, I see in the documentation you linked to that syntax errors are not handled.

Comment: Yep, it seems that unfortunately the TRY CATCH won't handle everything, so you'll definitely need to be careful if you're using a script like this unattended (i.e., as part of an automated job). Also, after rereading your question, since it doesn't handle syntax errors then this probably is not a sufficient answer. One question though, why do you think you'd run into syntax errors?

Comment: The script in question is automatically generated via code.  If the code has a bug in it, it may generate a script which is syntactically incorrect.  Of course, this is an issue that shouldn't happen for users if the code is well tested.  Thanks for the great answer; even though it doesn't handle syntax errors, it is a very comprehensive solution.  Accepted.